# How to determine on-chain from which type of wallet (e.g. Metamask or Ledger etc.) a transaction was sent?

Tags: transactions, wallet-transfer

I saw the twitter post below, where it is claimed that it is "easily discernible" if a transaction was sent by Metamask. And it does not refer to transactions from years ago, but from a fews days up to a few months. So I was wondering how this can be done. I assume this can be somehow approximated  from the transaction input or the raw transaction hex. Any ideas?

https://twitter.com/tayvano_/status/1648187051685314561?t=wBAVpU5COmzuTPXOAoRg2A&s=19

Answer (score 0):

There is no "on-chain way" to determine if a transaction is made from one type of wallet or another.

However the attacker in this example used mostly the **Swap** function from the **Metamask Swap Router** contract which is a feature included in the Metamask wallet.

In this case it is safe to assume that the attacker was using Metamask but their is no data on-chain that can prove that.